# Hive UDF 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.udf.UDFRowSequence' generating same value for first two records

Tags: hive, user-defined-functions, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to generate auto increment values using the Hive UDF UDFRowSequence, but its generating same id for first two records.

```
+-------+----------+---+-------------------+
|rank_id|     state| id|           datetime|
+-------+----------+---+-------------------+
|      1|New Jersey| 10|2018-03-27 10:00:00|
|      1|     Tamil| 25|2018-03-27 11:05:00|
|      2|   TamilNa| 25|2018-03-27 11:15:00|
|      3| TamilNadu| 25|2018-03-27 11:25:00|
|      4|   Gujarat| 30|2018-03-27 11:00:00|
+-------+----------+---+-------------------+
```

Here is the code that I am using for auto-increment .

```
package org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.udf;

import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Description;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.UDF;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.UDFType;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;

/**
 * UDFRowSequence.
 */
@Description(name = "row_sequence",
    value = "_FUNC_() - Returns a generated row sequence number starting from 1")
@UDFType(deterministic = false, stateful = true)
public class UDFRowSequence extends UDF
{
  private LongWritable result = new LongWritable();

  public UDFRowSequence() {
    result.set(0);
  }

  public LongWritable evaluate() {
    result.set(result.get() + 1);
    return result;
  }
}
```

Can anyone please tell me what wrong am I doing that is generating the same id for first two records.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, you are doing nothing wrong.
But, it seems no such solution exist.

The reason you are getting repeated numbers is mostly because your evaluation happens in 2 mappers (if you are using spark engine, then 2 executors). And, at each executor the UDF will start the sequence from 1.
So, same value for first 2 records is just by accident. Results may vary depending on how many mappers are used to run the query.

You can achieve what you want by restricting the number of executors to 1. From a spark perspective, I think you can use a `repartition(1)` operation.

Also have a look @ this [thread](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/20168/sequence-number-generation-in-hive.html) that has some useful points.